# Linux Kernel 4.18.0 , 5.0.0 and above and GNOME 3.30.0 and above not loading , why?

Tags: boot, gnome, kernel

I was trying to install KALI Linux 2019.3 on my laptop , it is of Kernel 5.2.9 and GNOME 3.30.2 from a bootable pendrive.
This installations were very easy for me before (i.e. while installing Kali versions 2017.3 and before).
But now the newer version of linux OS (any i.e. Kali , Parrot , Ubuntu etc.) based on Kernel 4.14.0 , 4.15.0 , 4.17.0 , 4.18.0 , 4.19.0 and 5.0 , 5.1 , 5.2 and above are not able to load on my laptop.
Whenever i boot into this OS's in any way (i.e. Live , Persistence , Install etc.), shows me an error sentences.

```
AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
 nvme0n1: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10
ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
```

Complete error images are linked below (Different Types)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCCIC.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyYZm.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZAxk.jpg

All the above error screens appear one or the other time.

I tried with all different versions of Linux OS's based on Kernel Kernel 4.18.0 ,  5.0.0 and above and Gnome 3.30.0 , but all those was a waste of time.

After all this what i came to know is that my pc is able to load kernel 4.17.0 and below very well , also we need to keep in mind the Gnome 3.28.0 and below.

This happens both in Legacy and UEFI mode.

Please any one give me the solution for this problem , and make my laptop load Kernel 4.18.0 , 5.0.0 and above and also GNOME 3.30.0 and above.

Configuration of my laptop is as follows,

```
Lenovo S540-15IWL Laptop (ideapad)
Processor: Intel I5-8265U CPU
Bios version: APCN31WW (Latest relese)
SSD: SAMSUNG MZVLB512HAJQ-000L2
Device SCSI\Disk&Ven_NVMe&Prod_SAMSUNG_MZVLB512\5&392c3b2a&0&000000 was migrated.
```

Comment: Crossposted on [super user](https://superuser.com/questions/1497079/linux-kernel-4-18-0-5-0-0-and-above-and-gnome-3-30-0-and-above-not-loading-w) and  [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617745/linux-kernel-4-18-0-5-0-0-and-above-and-gnome-3-30-0-and-above-not-loading-w)

Comment: Are there any BIOS options on this system to do with sleep or power states? It may be some of these changes: https://appuals.com/acpi-and-power-management-updates-merged-into-linux-4-19/  You could also report on bugzilla.kernel.org

Comment: Some comments suggest disabling secure boot and changing the drive to AHCI mode in the bios